# Loop through a list using VBA for excel, copy and paste the results for each item in the list

Tags: excel, vba

1 - I have a list "Equipment List" Cells B8:B54

2 - I have a drop down in "Equipment Task Sheet" Cell D7, which allows values from B8:B54 (above).  When I manually select a value in Cell D7, cells B45:X289 update.

3 - I would like to copy/paste the results (B45:x289) into another tab "Project Outline".  After copying and pasting, I would like to loop through all values B8:B54, and paste the results (B45:X289) after what was previously pasted.

I have the following code, and it almost works.

I get the correct number of "copy/paste" events, so the resulting table is the correct size (columsn and rows), but it just has one entry, without cycling through each possible entry in the list B8:B54).  Please let me know what I need to change.

```
Sub tgr()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsScen As Worksheet
    Dim wsComm As Worksheet
    Dim wsOuts As Worksheet
    Dim wsResults As Worksheet
    Dim rDDList As Range
    Dim rDDCell As Range
    Dim rDDValue As Range
    Dim rCopy As Range
    Dim rDest As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsScen = wb.Sheets("Equipment Task Sheet")
    Set wsComm = wb.Sheets("Equipment List")
    Set wsOuts = wb.Sheets("Project Outline")
     
    Set rDDList = wsComm.Range("B8:B11")
    Set rDDValue = wsScen.Range("C2")
    Set rCopy = wsScen.Range("B45:X289")
    Set rDest = wsOuts.Range("A2")

    For Each rDDCell In rDDList.Cells
        rDDValue.Value = rDDCell.Value
        rDest.Resize(rCopy.Rows.Count, rCopy.Columns.Count).Value = rCopy.Value
        Set rDest = rDest.Offset(rCopy.Rows.Count, 0)
    Next rDDCell

End Sub
```

Comment: So part of the results include the original list? (`B8:B54` overlaps `B45:X289` at `B45:B54`). Why loop and not copy the entire range at once?

Comment: For clarification, B8:B54 is in the tab "Equipment List", and B45:X289 is in the tab "Equipment Task Sheet" - so they are part of different ranges of cells.  Also, in my example above I have B8:B11 as the range, I will change that to B8:B54 after I resolve this bug.

Comment: rCopy is never changed, so rCopy.Rows.Count will always be 245.  Create a variable to hold the Row.Count value and then increment the value with each loop.

Comment: I made a quick test, you macro does well for wb.Sheets("Equipment List").Range("B8:B11").

Answer (score 0):

Add a j counter so it adds to the bottom of the list.

```
 Set rDDList = wsComm.Range("B7")
 Set rDDValue = wsScen.Range("C2")
 Set rCopy = wsScen.Range("B45:X289")
 Set rDest = wsOuts.Range("A2")

 j=0
 Each rDDCell In rDDList.Cells
    rDDValue.Value = rDDList.offset(i,0).value
    rDest.Resize(rCopy.Rows.Count, rCopy.Columns.Count).Value = rCopy.Value
    rowOffset = rCopy.Rows.Count + j*(rCopy.rows.Count)
    Set rDest = rDest.Offset(rowOffset, 0)
    j=j+1
Next rDDCell
```